# How to use one function which might have different parameter sets

Tags: r, function, arguments

I have a complex function in which I would like to use a nested function which is dependent on a parameter of the parent function. How do I do this if each option of the nested function requires a different parameter set?

This is a toy example

```
#all my function options (there are several and the idea is that I can easily add new ones without altering the parent function)

a1 <- function(x,y){
    return(x+y)
}

a2 <- function(x,y,z){
    return(x+y+z)
}

# the parent function
complexfun <- function(a,b,c,...){
    x = b+c
    y = (b+c)^2
    z = sqrt(b+c)
    myfun=get(a)
    ret=myfun(x,y,z)
    return(ret)
}

# obviously, when I run this than I have an error
complexfun(a='a1',b=1,c=1)
Error in myfun(x, y, z) : unused argument (z)

#if I remove the z, it's the other way around...
complexfun(a='a2',b=1,c=1)
Error in myfun(x, y) : argument "z" is missing, with no default
```

It might be a very simply thing to do but right now I don't see a clean solution.

Comment: In this, presumably, toy case, you can use a single function with three parameters and test for z with `if missing(z)`. Then you can `return(x+y)` if missing and `return(x+y+z)` if not. The other option with separate functions `a1` and `a2` is to test for the value of parameter `a` and run the appropriate function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that it is possible to pass the function itself although the code below will also work if you pass a character string with its name.  Use ... to pass the other arguments so that their number is not fixed. `a1` and `a2` are as in the question.

```
# the parent function
complexfun <- function(a, ...) {
  a <- match.fun(a)
  a(...)
}

complexfun(a1, 1, 2)
## [1] 3
complexfun(a2, 1, 2, 3)
## [1] 6
```

An alternative using x, y, z defined in the function.  This computes the number of arguments to the function `a` and then passes only that many.

```
complexfun <- function(a,b,c,...){
    x <- b + c
    y <- (b + c)^2
    z <- sqrt(b + c)
    nargs <- length(as.list(a)) - 1
    L <- list(x, y, z)
    do.call(a, head(L, nargs))
}

complexfun(a1, 1, 2)
## [1] 12

complexfun(a2, 1, 2)
## [1] 13.73205
```

Comment: Your answer is interesting but in my example I put x,y and z within the function because they are matrices/lists that are computed based on the parameters. So I unfortunately can't use this solution.

Comment: Have added alternative.